# How can I write a rule that selects on all pages?

Tags: krl

In KRL (Kynetx Rule Language), how can I write a select statement that selects on all pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the select statements for web events in KRL are regular expressions you can use the following select statement to fire on all pages viewed:

```
select when web pageview ".*"
```

Example in context of full ruleset:

```
ruleset a60x425 {
  meta {
    name "test select on all pages"
    description <<
      this will select on all pageviews
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  dispatch { }

  rule selection_test_on_all_pages {
    select when web pageview ".*"
    {
      notify("I selected on this page!","woot!") with sticky = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Note 1: This doesn't address the issue of dispatch domains and browser extensions. This will work as expected when executed from a bookmarklet. Browser extensions won't make it to the selection expression unless the currently viewed domain matches a domain set in the dispatch block. This examples dispatch domain is blank because I am making the assumption that the app will be run from a bookmarklet.

Note 2: Selection expressions get compiled into a regular expression so it's important to remember that you don't need to use the 're//' format for the expression like you do everywhere else in language you use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
select when pageview ".*"
```